# How to count conflicts when comparing 3 file versions?

Tags: git, merge, diff, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm trying to compare 3 files with "diff3". I aim to count the number of conflicts that require manual merge (when both versions are different than the original version).

The basic syntax is `diff3 mine older yours` but I can't find out how to get the conflicts only. I have to know if there are two conflict sections, three conflict sections or 140.

Thank you

Comment: If you know about an alternative to "diff3" please let me know about. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

When git detects conflicts in your files, it will leave conflict resolution markers for each conflict in those files, which look something like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> <sha>
```

If you do a simple grep of your files for these conflict markers and pass them to word count, you can get the total number of conflicts:

```bash
grep --recursive '<<<<<<< HEAD' * | wc --lines
```

Here's a version that uses `git status` to specifically list files that have conflict markers, which should give you less files to search for using `grep`:

```bash
git status --porcelain | \
grep --extended-regex '^(A|U){2}' | \
cut --characters 4- | \
xargs grep 'HEAD' | \
wc --lines
```